# jQuery setCustomValidity not displaying error message, but is preventing submit

Tags: jquery

I have this on submit code:

```
$("#homeForm").on("submit", function(e){
        var email = document.getElementById("confirmationEmail");
        if ($('#email').val() != $('#confirmationEmail').val()) {
            email.setCustomValidity("Email did not match.");
            email.reportValidity();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        else
        {
            email.setCustomValidity("");
        }

    });
```

And here is my HTML

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email*</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" required />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="confirmationEmail">Confirmation Email*</label>
                    <input type="email" name="confirmationEmail" id="confirmationEmail" class="form-control" required />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Now when the emails do not match my code does not do the submit, however the custom message I am trying to add does not display, any idea why?

THanks,

**UPDATE**

Okay so the message does display (there was other code preventing it from showing, new problem even when the email and confirmationEmail match, I still get the Email did not match custom message, I added a bunch of console.logs before the condition and they are not firing on the second try.